# How to get rid of deforming small prints?

Tags: slic3r, warping

When printing a big base on the bed, I got no warping, but once I print small part (3 or less inches wide), there is a bit of warping on my piece as I remove it.

[image: Example print]

It is 2 inches wide by 1 mm thick by the base. It seems to be well sticked to the bed while printing, but once removed, it bends a bit. I tried multiple times and it bends at a different place.

I was wondering if it may be thicker if it won't bend at all.

Can you guys help me with it?

Here my Slic3r settings:

```
# generated by PrusaSlicer 2.1.0+win64 on 2019-10-19 at 11:38:38 UTC
avoid_crossing_perimeters = 0
bed_temperature = 60
bottom_fill_pattern = rectilinear
bottom_solid_layers = 7
brim_width = 5
cooling = 1
end_filament_gcode = "; Filament-specific end gcode \n;END gcode for filament\n"
end_gcode = M104 S0 ; turn off temperature\nG28 X0 Y0 ; home X and Y axis\nG1 Z210 F5000 ; Send Z to top\nM84     ; disable motors\n
ensure_vertical_shell_thickness = 1
external_perimeter_extrusion_width = 0.45
external_perimeter_speed = 50%
extrusion_multiplier = 1
extrusion_width = 0.45
fan_always_on = 1
filament_diameter = 1.75
filament_settings_id = "FlyingBear Ghost 4"
filament_type = PLA
fill_angle = 45
fill_density = 20%
fill_pattern = stars
first_layer_bed_temperature = 65
first_layer_extrusion_width = 0.42
first_layer_height = 0.2
first_layer_speed = 30
first_layer_temperature = 200
infill_extrusion_width = 0.45
infill_overlap = 25%
infill_speed = 80
layer_height = 0.1
nozzle_diameter = 0.4
perimeter_extruder = 1
perimeter_extrusion_width = 0.45
perimeter_speed = 45
print_settings_id = FlyingBear Ghost 4
printer_settings_id = FlyingBear Ghost 4
printer_technology = FFF
retract_before_travel = 1
retract_before_wipe = 0%
retract_layer_change = 1
retract_length = 0.8
retract_length_toolchange = 10
retract_lift = 0
retract_lift_above = 0
retract_lift_below = 209
retract_restart_extra = 0
retract_restart_extra_toolchange = 0
retract_speed = 40
seam_position = aligned
```

As I said, I got no problem adhering to the bed, it's when I remove it from the bed it becomes deformed.

Comment: @EricBrochu you can't switch comments to answers. Often, very "common" errors tend to end in comments first as a first step of troubleshooting, which then get formulated out into answers later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pla is flexible and can be shaped at temperatures as low as 50 deg C. To prevent deforming your prints in removing them, you should wait for the bed to reach room temperature. This takes about 5 minutes after a print ended.